# p.then is not a function, error with angular parser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the next Json:

```
[{
  "given": "given3",
  "when": "when3",
  "then": "then asjdh"
}, {
  "given": "given1",
  "when": "when1",
  "then": "then asjdh"  
}, {
  "given": "given2",
  "when": "when2",
  "then": "then asjdh"
}]
```

and when I try to do:

```
<ul class="phones">
    <li ng-repeat="behavior in behaviors" >

      <p>GIVEN: {{behavior.given}}</p>
      <p>WHEN: {{behavior.when}}</p>
      <p>THEN: {{behavior.then}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I have the next error:

```
Error: p.then is not a function
anonymous@file:/~/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6531
lex/readIdent/token.fn<@file:/~/app/lib/angular/angular.js:5914
$interpolate/fn@file:/~/app/lib/angular/angular.js:4931
Scope.prototype.$digest@file:/~/app/lib/angular/angular.js:7889
Scope.prototype.$apply@file:/~/app/lib/angular/angular.js:8097
done@file:/~/app/lib/angular/angular.js:9111
completeRequest@file:/~/app/lib/angular/angular.js:9274
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@file:/~/app/lib/angular/angular.js:9245
"
```

well i don't understand so much about how angular parse the information in json, but i think "then" is a reserved word, or something like that?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you post the source code please?

Comment: yes,I push it on github http://kcy.me/qnrv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well... i solved using a simple replace in the controller.

```
/* Controllers */

function behaveListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('behaveMe/behaves.json').success(function(data) {

    for(var i in data){
        data[i].Then = data[i].then;
        delete data[i].then;
    }

    $scope.behaviors = data;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that then is used in the promise API and you are using it as a data key for your model.  It sees that "then" is defined and tries to execute it, but then is a string, not a function.

[Promise API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)